# Access Android Camera Frames with no Preview

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, surfaceview

I want to do image processing on frames from Android Camera in real time with OpenCv, but all the OpenCv Android examples provide a preview of the image being captured. I really don't need previews of the frames , is there any way to get the frames without actually showing the preview ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick/naive way would be to make `onCameraFrame` method returning null and set your `CameraBridgeViewBase` visibility to `SurfaceView.INVISIBLE` or `SurfaceView.GONE`.

Comment: Returning null does the job but setting visibility to INVISIBLE/GONE causes not calling onCameraFrame at all.

Answer (score -1):

I still would like to know if it worked for you, but meanwhile I found the solution that worked for me. As I feel grateful for the guy who wrote it, I'm [sharing this](http://wearecoder.com/questions/kt50o/opencv-3-1-0-android-hide-camera-preview) (scroll down to answers section) with anyone who will have same problem in future.

In case the link vanished, here's his/her pro-tip:

> You can set your preview (in this case a `CameraBridgeViewBase`)
>   transparent by setting the alpha value of the view, with 0 being
>   completely invisible.
>
> `mOpenCvCameraView.setAlpha(0);`
>
> This should make your preview "disappear".

---

I wonder how your solution works, because as you can read in the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2.html):

> This method is invoked when delivery of the frame needs to be done.
>   The returned values - is a modified frame which needs to be displayed
>   on the screen.

Indeed, in my case it doesn't work but I desperately need such a functionality.